# Excel/Formula limitation with 255 characters with if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Good morning,
I would like to check the cell to see if they are fall into A, B or C categories with the excel formula below,

```
=IF(CB3=0,"",
(IF(N3="
215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 336, ","A",

IF(N3="215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, "B",

IF(N3="301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 336, ","C",
IF(LEN(N3)=0,"",LEFT(N3,(LEN(N3)-2))))))))
```

And I've seen 255 text limits error so that I can't process it, The excel said that I can utilize a CONCATENATE or &, but have no idea what I can do with this. Any suggestions? Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Try using another formula, can you explain what you need and show your Data?

Comment: What I need to see from it, I want the cell to show me the cell falls in the categories (A, B or C) and if not, just show a set of bunch of models. (etc: 215, 216, 217..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining about this one very long text string that you are testing for:

```
"215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 336, "
```

Instead, use concatenation to break it up:

```
CONCATENATE("215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251,", " 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 336, ")
```

These two are functionally equivalent as concatenate just sticks the two strings together into one long one.

So... all we are doing here is breaking up your very long string like:

```
="This is a very long string, isn't it"
```

Into two smaller strings and concatenating them together:

```
=Concatenate("This is a very long ", "string, isn't it")
```

These two formulas are functionally equivalent since the resulting value will be

```
This is a very long string, isn't it
```

Comment: =IF(CC3=0,IF(N3=CONCATENATE(215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, ),"A", I tried with these but it throws me 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, not A, am I missing something? Thanks JNevill!

Comment: You are needing to concatenate two strings, which need to be in quotation marks. Your attempt here is concatenating many number values together. If you are confused about how `=concatenate()` works, try it outside of this very big `if` formula to see what results.  Your formula should look like: `=IF(CC3=0,IF(N3=CONCATENATE("215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251,", " 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 336, "),"A",`